# jQuery Youtube player

Tags: php, jquery, youtube-javascript-api

This is a two parter:

I've been trying to get this to work but I am new to coding. I want to click on the button `#video` and a remote div `#imageMain` will play.

I have written the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var videoURL = <?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['video']; ?>;
        $('#video').click(function(e) {
            $('#imageMain').html('<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="435" height="244" src="' + videoURL + '" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, with this script in place, there is a script straight after in the HTML that breaks. If I delete this script the other works fine.

Comment: If not clear I get the youtube URL from a database

Answer (score 0):

`videoUrl` needs to be in quotes, because it's a string:

```
var videoURL = '<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['video']; ?>';
```

I would imagine that is the error that is affecting your second code block too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, the string should be wrapped in double quotes since the word video already has single quotes.

Comment: @arttronics The internal single quotes are PHP, the external are javascript. They will not interfere. Any decent IDE will show that in it's syntax highlighter.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, The internal and external quotes needs to be different since the whole line is JavaScript. For example, if the word **video** was a variable then it would be prepend/append with a + to add it to the string. Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JcLLc/) and when you check with jsLint you will see errors. My syntax highlighting apps. show's a broken string.

Comment: **You are completely wrong.** The PHP is interpreted on the **server**, so the javascript rendered to the browser will be `var videoURL = 'http://myvideo.com/file.swf';` Now I would appreciate it if you undo your downvote and then go and educate yourself.

Comment: His markup is in the Head Section of the HTML page, written in between script tags. I provided reference to WiKi explaining about JavaScript Delimiters when used with variables. I agree that double same quotes are allowed in PHP, but the markup, as it stands, is a JavaScript variable. The jsFiddle also confirms the syntax is incorrect, which means the server will not have the full string to process. I hope that's clear and sheds some light on the subject.

Comment: Ahh, I see your confusion Rory. The variable is to be a JavaScript string for use in the next line below... within the iframe markup that's dynamically created. No, I never did server side coding but I know a JavaScript error when I see one.

Comment: This is what I think Rory: The videoURL is to be used as a JavaScript string as I indicated. Then, that string which is PHP markup is injected into the dynamically created iframe, as unprocessed PHP. Once the iframe is ready to be shown, the PHP is then processed within the iframe and replaced by a video URL as you indicated. Also, the iframe already is providing quotes right before the variable videoURL is inserted, which may be redundant. I added extra tag of PHP to this question as it's interesting. Thanks for your feedback and I will follow up as soon as I can.

Comment: I believe the full scope of the SO question was missed entirely, but have completed all updates as promised along with a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing this answer out of necessity.

The **correct method** to create a JavaScript variable is:

```
var videoURL = "<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['video']; ?>";
```

Also, the following syntax is also acceptable:

```
var videoURL = '<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem["video"]; ?>';
```

Note that **either method** can not have duplicate sets of quotes because quotes are **string delimiters** in **JavaScript**. Reference [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_quotation) here for more info.

I believe the **PHP** is to be interpreted after it's inside the iframe markup when that's dynamically created, *not before that time*, specifically, during a **jQuery Click Event** since that in itself is rendering the iframe.

Comment: As I mentioned to your comment on my answer, you may want to read about server-side languages, as the code between `<?php ... ?>` will be interpreted by the server first. The quotes between those areas are irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Rory, I will do that and revoke my answer if it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This **entirely different answer** is provided after the SO Question is **fully** realized.

Because your **goal** is to have a **jQuery Click Event** that in turn will play the video at id **#video**, you will need to use one of a few **[YouTube API's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)** to invoke the **YouTube play Method**.

YouTube has their default Flash API which is based on their Flash AS3 Player, but they also have a HTML5 YouTube Video Player with Flash fallback depending on your project needs.

The [Flash API Playground](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) allows you to test API options, and the website has a practical [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) shown for starting up a video in a iframe using their Embed API tools.

That practicle example is shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9xde/) along with an `alert` indicating the video is about to be played using the **API YouTube `.playVideo()`** command to the iframe which is what your goal and question is about (*Potential PHP issues notwithstanding*).

As far as **my other SO answer** which is based on **embedding the iframe player** during a jQuery Click Event, anyone who can shed light into that syntax and my understanding of **embedding PHP** (at time of iframe creation) in the manner I suggested and think it's incorrect would be positively appreciated.

Also, if your intent is to inject a `videoID` URL at the time of the **jQuery Click Event**, which may be random depending on what **`row`** was clicked, please do say so.